# Microsoft.Office.Interop error even after installing PIAs

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop, office-pia

We have a large project which builds fine on several machines.  I am in the process of installing a development system on a new machine and have a problem building because the Microsoft.Office.Interop namespace is missing.
I have Office 2010 installed and have installed the PIAs.  I have removed/re-added the Office references in the project - they still seem to have the yellow triangle.
Still no luck.

Could there be anything I haven't tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing something wrong while adding the reference. You could see to these similar threads if they are of help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054365/1493524
- [PIA's Installed but still receiving interop error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11484894/1493524)
- [Adding Office 2010 Interop (PIA) in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611296/office-2010-pia-not-being-installed?rq=1)